# Search site that searches other search sites

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, search, rss

I'm using a MVC 4 style to make a site that uses 4 other sites to search through. I have figured out how to consume the RSS feeds from the sites, but now I do not know how to actually display these results on my UI. Any ideas on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have retrieved the RSS feeds using ajax, it's simple enough to implement a data binding library such as Knockout.js and create a template that renders the result.

I.E. AJAX retrieves RSS feed XML, XML is parsed in to JSON, JSON is used to render template.

I would check the terms of service for the search engines you are using to make sure you aren't breaking them as well.